# Error "ssh_exchange_identification" with Corkscrew

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunneling, http-proxy, tunneling

I'm trying to reach my ssh server (i'm behind a corporate proxy) so I tried to use Corkscrew.
My ssh server is listening on port 443, I put `sshd: ALL` in my /etc/hosts.allow and there's nothing into my /etc/hosts.deny.

I'm using the following command to launch a ssh session over Corkscrew :

```
ssh -D991 -p443 user@ssh_server_ip -o"ProxyCommand corkscrew proxy_ip proxy_port %h %p proxy_username proxy_password"
```

But I get the following error : `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

I had the same issue when I was trying to use httptunnel (hts) and I wasn't behind a proxy (it was at home for tests).

How can I fix that?

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can connect to plaintext services? Check that you can reach simple TCP sockets before trying SSH. Could it also be that your corporate proxy is messing up the sent information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the -o option, I've edited my ssh config with the following lines:

`Host 5.39.79.49
Port 443
ProxyCommand corkscrew ip port %h %p loginpassfile`

Corkscrew doesn't work when I directly specify the user and the password but it works when I use a password-file. So problem solved but I don't really know why.